# What port does Azure Mobile Service uses?

Tags: security, azure, port, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently developing a Mobile application, which leverage on Azure Mobile Service as the server side.
However, due to some constrain of our cooperate network, **I'm not able to get my SQL database data from Mobile Service**. I have 2 questions here in order to solve the problem.

1. **which exactly port Azure Mobile Service** uses?
2. By default which port does it the Mobile Service use to talk to Azure SQL database?    Is that port 1433 as well?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/02/07/azure-ports.aspx
I found this article "Outbound ports that have to be opened for Azure development" but it doesn't talk about Azure Mobile Service.
Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Services is essentially a web api and so app->backend communication is done over port 443.

mobile backend -> database communication is governed by the connection string used; by default port 1433 will be used.

To access on premises databases consider using [Hybrid Connections](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-hybrid-connections-get-started/)